# Chrome debugger : Is it possible to halt the script in the debugger every time a Nan or Infinity is computed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, nan

I would like the debugger in Chrome halt on the line where a numeric computation produces a NaN or Infinity.
Is this possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript :How to set a Conditional Break Point in Chrome debugger tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598561/javascript-how-to-set-a-conditional-break-point-in-chrome-debugger-tools)

Comment: @Vishwanath But that requires the breakpoint/expression to be known - which is different than handling the NaN like a [Signaling NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Signaling_NaN). It is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Hmmm right.. Answer given by David seems to me the most close that you can get..

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. If you know the place where the computation is being made, you can put a conditional breakpoint on the result. On a regular breakpoint, right click and click on Edit Breakpoint.

An alternative would be to "Pause on Exceptions" as NaN and Infinity will generally cause problems pretty close to where they were computed.

Comment: There is already a feature request for this issue : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396021