# Expanding and exploring json objects without having to console.log(obj) them

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting into js and debugging a sdk for a start.. I am finding that I have to follow functions and then when I want to see the properties of a variable I have to console.log(variable) inside whatever function and at a point in that function where I want to see the variable, isn't there an easier way where I can just see the current state of an object? When I say current state I mean, it's end state after the function has run, which doesn't change, so I should be able to just go oh look that's the last known state of var cart; I'll just explore that cause I know it hasn't change. I'm doing this so I can see things like obj.options easily, I'm using chromes debugger, that shouldn't be too hard?

I don't need break points because I know that this variable won't change after I run the function, so for me to have to write console.log(etc..) to be able to inspect the state and attributes and what ever. I can't just open a variables array in say chrome debugger?

Comment: you can, depending on where you storing those variables. if they are global variables you should have access to them from within debugger

Comment: You can type the name of any global variable in the console to inspect it.

Comment: Do you familiar with this: [How to set a Conditional Break Point in Chrome debugger tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598561/javascript-how-to-set-a-conditional-break-point-in-chrome-debugger-tools)

Comment: this is my debugger https://gyazo.com/b85956c8e93b13b5cc320e31f7aa5188

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @nnnnnn hahaha thank you, I'm still learning, so what is it, it's just an object?

Comment: Yep, just an object. The article I linked to goes into detail about it, but basically JSON is a data interchange format, a way of serialising an object as a string for transmission or storage - so in JavaScript, unless the variable you're dealing with contains a string it is not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *do* need breakpoints, because you need to stop the evaluation of the code at a point in time so you can inspect the variables, which you can do simply by hovering the mouse over them:

[image]

Having stopped on the breakpoint, I hovered the `foo` that's outlined in red until the box popped up, then used the arrow next to `question` to expand that. You can keep doing that to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you can do here, is to put a breakpoint at the end of the function (or in any other place, where you object is in scope), right click on it -> Edit Breakpoint. This way you can create conditional breakpoint. It will break only if condition is evaluated to truthy value. So if you put there `console.log(youObject)`, which returns `undefined`, there will be no stop at this breakpoint, but you can see your object in Console.

See below:
[image]

Output in Console will be:

[image]